# Have a 0/unconfirmed transaction stuck over 12 hours

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

This is my first time using bitcoin and I've had a transaction stuck for over 12 hours.   Any help getting confirmed would be appreciated.

https://blockchain.info/tx/0b17a765b1f4a1a7e53a47b6da287b86211ea64126192ffc26a1d6d8920eab7a

Comment: Your transaction did not include a transaction fee. It will probably take days until it is confirmed or may never be. This can be fixed creating another transaction that spends the same money, but includes a transaction fee. Which wallet did you use?

Comment: Also see: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it

Comment: bitcoin-core .  I thought it set recommended fees

Comment: Strange. What version was that?

Comment: Bitcoin Core version v0.12.0 (64-bit)

Comment: This was my 1st bitcoin transfer and I didn't realize anything about fees and such..  but  as ive been reading now for 13 hours different posts on 0 unconfirmed transactions I'm not sure how to proceed with either cancelling or waiting till it confirms

Comment: Depends on how urgently you wish to resolve the issue. If you have a few days, you could wait for the transaction to no longer be broadcasted, then run Bitcoin Core with `-zapwallettxes` to make it forget about the transaction. You could then send **all** your money to yourself, to overwrite the transaction.
Or you could try to doublespend, by running Bitcoin Core with `-zapwallettxes` now. However, other nodes would send you your first tx back, so you'd probably want to go offline until you've created the new transaction. As most nodes don't relay doublespends, it might still take a few days.

Comment: im trying to run the bitcoind with the -zapwallettxes flag.   I really dont know what im doing.  Probably  going to lose the coins.

Comment: If you don't feel comfortable trying to fix it by yourself, please find someone to help you. `-zapwallettxes` forgets the transactions you have sent and can find past ones by re-reading the blockchain. Since this was your first transaction and it is not confirmed yet, you shouldn't see any effect except for that one transaction disappearing. Bitcoind flags are explained more here: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin

Answer (score 3):

I ran bitcoind with the --zapwallettxes flag and recovered the coins.  Thankyou for the help